# modeling Knapsack with petri net

Tags: modeling, knapsack-problem, petri-net

I am new at petri net. what are the steps of drawing a petri net graph for Knapsack problem?

Is petri net suitable for modeling this problem?

Comment: @Dmitri Chubarov can you help me about this question?

Comment: Could you give a bit of background on why are you trying to use Petri nets in the context of opimization problems?

Comment: @Dmitri Chubarov My professor ask that in the class I explain how can step by step modeling one problem such as Travelling salesman or knapsack or bridge of Königsberg or etc. which can suitable for modeling with petri net.

Comment: Suddenly this is starting to make sense. If you take TSP or Knapsack as feasibility problems, i.e. "if there exists a path" or "if there exists a packing" than there is something you can try to model with Petri Nets. Will try to post more details later on.